# Error Debug Assertion Failed. BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID

Tags: c++, string, oop, assertions

When I run my program the a window with the message "Debug Assertion Failed" appears.

Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"

using namespace std;    
String :: String ()    
{    
    this->s=new char[50];
}

String :: String(char *sir)    
{    
    this->s=new char[strlen(sir)+1];
    strcpy_s(this->s, strlen(sir)+1, sir);
}

String :: ~String()    
{    
    delete [] s;
}

String& String:: operator=(String &sir)    
{       
    strcpy_s(this->s, strlen(sir.s)+1, sir.s);
    return *this;

}

String String:: operator+(String sir)    
{    
    String rez;
    rez.s=new char [strlen(s)+strlen(sir.s)+1];
    strcpy_s(rez.s, strlen(s)+1,s);
    strcat_s(rez.s, strlen(s)+strlen(sir.s)+1, sir.s);
    return rez;

}

void String:: afisare()    
{    
    cout << s<< endl;
}

bool String:: operator==(String sir)    
{    
    if(strcmp(s, sir.s)==0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}`
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>    
#include "Header.h"

using namespace std;

int main()    
{
    String sir1("John ");
    String sir2("Ola ");
    String rez;
    if(sir1==sir2)
        cout << "string are identicaly"<< endl;
    else
        cout << "strings are not identicaly"<< endl;

    rez=sir1+sir2; // this line i have debug assertion failed
    rez.afisare();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `String& String:: operator=(String &sir)` what happens when `strlen(sir.s)+1` is longer than `this->s`

Comment: Read about the *rule of three/five/zero*.

Comment: You are also missing the copy constructor. `String(const String &sir)`.

Comment: be very careful when using a symbol `String` and having `using namespace std;` in fact I would suggest getting rid of the `using` all together.

Comment: Good thing `std::string` is lower case. Would there be any conflicts??

Comment: @drescherjm with `using namespace std;`, the answer is always "not yet"...

Comment: @drescherjm only the highly likely fat fingered ones. As far as I'm aware the reserved names are all case sensitive, that said `namespace std` does expand over time, so pulling all of it into the global namespace is generally bad.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few issues in this code that could lead to this particular error. The error occurs when you attempt to free memory that has been corrupted.

I suspect in your case this is happening in your `operator==`. This is taking in `String` instead of `const String&`. The difference is that by taking in `String` you're making a copy of the operand. That includes a reference to the internal buffer you're story as a raw pointer. Thus when that copy goes out of scope that buffer is then `delete[]`ed. As such by the time you're attempting to call your `operator+` the buffer doesn't exist. The runtime then alerts you to the undefined behavior via the assertion message. If instead you passed in `const String&` you'd be passing in a reference to the parameter that cannot be changed rather than making a copy. This would ensure that it is not destructed at the end of the method and the buffer is not `delete[]`ed.

Side note: if you switched your buffer to be a `std::vector<char>` instead of a raw buffer you'd be better served as that manages its own memory and you wouldn't need a destructor.